# TrueType RTL fonts doesn't work in jasperreport exported PDFs

Tags: jasper-reports, report, truetype, right-to-left, persian

I'm making a report includes a chart using jasperreports 4.7 in iReport. My report contains some persian RTL text which uses a persian TTF font (& I've configured jasperreport to embed this font in PDF files).
When I'm testing the result in iReport internal viewer, everything is OK, but when I export it as PDF, the chart text seems corrupts & it works just when render type of chart is 'image'.
In addition, the same report doesn't work (even when I choose 'image' as the chart render type) on my debian server (the font is embedded & exists on exported document properties in all of those situations).
Any idea?

Comment: Did you use the [***Font Extensions***](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions) mechanism?

Comment: @AlexK : yes, I've exported a font extention from iReport & I've includede it in my classpath (The texts with the same font out of the chart have no problem, seems only charts have problem in using fonts)

Comment: I have the exact same problem and I found out that there is a problem with JfreeChart which is used by jasper. it renders the charts with graphics2d which does not render RTL languages properly. but i am using dynamicReports so i cant even change the render type. if you have managed to solve this problem please share the solution here. tnx in advance.

Comment: @user2304200: I just recompiled same report with JasperSoft Studio (instead of iReport) & the problem gone! As I remember, the version of jasperreport library is the same in both cases!

Comment: @EhsanKhodarahmi: thanks for your help but i am using dynamic reports in a big project and this is the last feature. so i cant change it to anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a project. We ended up adding our font's ttf file into the jasper jar archive. This way jasper recognizes the font and exports accordingly.